# Returning a list of the ordered elements with a conition in while loop structure

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to solve a assignment where are 13 lights and starting from 1, light is turned off at every 5th light, when the count reaches 13, start from 1st item again. The function should return the order of lights turned off. In this case, for a list of 13 items, the return list would be `[5, 10, 2, 8, 1, 9, 4, 13, 12, 3, 7, 11, 6]`. Also, turned off lights would not count again.

So the way I was going to approach this problem was to have a list named `turnedon`, which is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]` and an empty list called `orderoff` and append to this list whenever a light gets turned off in the `turnedon` list. So while the `turnedon` is not empty, iterate through the `turnedon` list and append the light getting turned off and remove that `turnedoff` light from the `turnedon` list, if that makes sense. I cannot figure out what should go into the while loop though. Any idea would be really appreciated.

```
def orderoff():
    n=13
    turnedon=[]
    for n in range(1,n+1):
        turnedon.append(n)
    orderoff=[]

    while turneon !=[]:
```

Comment: `[5, 10, 2, 8, 1, 9, 4, 13, 12, 3, 7, 11, 6]` does not look correct. 5-1 = 4, 10-5 = 5, 2-10 = 5 -- numbers are different, 4 or 5

Comment: @lenik - *"Also, turned off lights would not count again."* You count 5 steps to light #5, then 5 steps to light #10, then 5 steps to light #2, then the next 5 steps goes to light #8 because #5 is already off so you shouldn't count it. The solution based on pure modulo arithmetic won't give correct results because it doesn't have this behaviour.

Comment: What is your expected output if the number of items and the step are not coprime?

Comment: @FBruzzesi With e.g. 4 lights and a step size of 2, the first light turned off is #2, then #4, then the remaining lights are #1 and #3 so stepping by 2 means #3 is turned off next. So the output would be [2, 4, 3, 1].

Comment: @kaya3 thank you for the clarification, your previous comment made me realize that already.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is equivalent to the well-known [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), in which `n` prisoners stand in a circle, and they are killed in a sequence where each time, the next person to be killed is `k` steps around the circle from the previous person; the steps are only counted over the remaining prisoners. A sample solution in Python can be found on the [Rosetta code website](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#Python), which I've adapted slightly below:

```py
def josephus(n, k):
    p = list(range(1, n+1))
    i = 0
    seq = []
    while p:
        i = (i+k-1) % len(p)
        seq.append(p.pop(i))
    return seq
```

Example:

```py
>>> josephus(13, 5)
[5, 10, 2, 8, 1, 9, 4, 13, 12, 3, 7, 11, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you!! However, what is k representing in the function?

Comment: `k` is the number of steps you count each time; 5 in your example.

Comment: also may I ask in the line, i = (i+k-1) % len(p), i is first 4 and then 8. So a[4]=5 so is it right but since a[8]=9, it would not be the right number to come next? Could you explain the logic? Thanks!

Comment: The list is originally `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`, so the value at index 4 is 5. But the value at index 4 is removed from the list, so it becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`, and then the new value at index 4 + 5 - 1 = 8 is 10, not 9. The -1 in the formula is to compensate for the fact that the previous value gets removed from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more optimal solution would be to use a loop, add the displacement each time, and use modules to keep the number in range

```
def orderoff(lights_num,step):
    turnd_off=[]
    num =0
    for i in range(max):
        num =((num+step-1)%lights_num)+1
        turnd_off.append(num)
    return turnd_off

print(orderoff(13))
```

Comment: Just for best practice, I would suggest to avoid using the name `max` for a variable, since it is a built-in function. Moreover since you create a function, it is worth it to pass a step parameter instead of hard-coding it

Comment: your result: `[5, 10, 2, 7, 12, 4, 9, 1, 6, 11, 3, 8, 13]` is different from what OP quoted

Answer (score 1):

This works, but the results are different from yours:

```
>>> pos = 0
>>> result = []
>>> while len(result) < 13 :
...     pos += 5
...     pos %= 13
...     if pos not in result :
...         result.append(pos)
... 
>>> result = [i+1 for i in result]  # make it 1-based, not 0-based
>>> result
[6, 11, 3, 8, 13, 5, 10, 2, 7, 12, 4, 9, 1]
>>>
```